# A question about moment-generating function

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a r.v. and $\phi(\theta)=\mathbb{E}(e^{\theta X})$

Let $\theta_+=\sup \{\theta:\phi(\theta)<\infty\}$  $\theta_-=\inf \{\theta:\phi(\theta)<\infty\}$

Why $\phi(\theta)<\infty$ for $\theta\in(\theta_-,\theta_+)$? since $\phi$ doesn't have monotonicity？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\exp$ is convex, if $\theta = t \theta_1 + (1-t) \theta_2$ where $0 \le t \le 1$ we have $e^{\theta x} \le t e^{\theta_1 x} + (1-t) e^{\theta_2 x}$ for all real $x$.  Now take expected value.

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi(\theta_1) < \infty, \phi(\theta_2) < \infty$ with $\theta_1 < \theta_2 $, then $\phi(\theta) < \infty， \forall \theta \in [\theta_1, \theta_2]$.

This is because $e^{\theta X}$ is convex as a function of $\theta$, for all values of $X$